# What is a word or phrase that describes something that offers no context or value?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm currently looking at revamping a [list of options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252844/make-comment-flags-less-stupid).  One of the possible choices  is called 'Noisy' meaning that this offers nothing of value to anyone reading the problem.  However, I'm not sure 'Noisy' is the right term for what I'm looking for. Other possibilities that don't seem to fit are noisy, not needed, unnecessary.

Is there a word or a phrase that means 'something is uneeded or offers no value' when looking at a topic?    An example would be:

> This should be deleted or removed because it is _______.

Comment: Are you trying to say it has nothing to do with the subject at hand or that it adds no value to the post?

Comment: @Hank Ideally, it would be either one.  I'm looking for some way to say it's just not needed - one word or phrase would be perfect - if it's possible.

Comment: I can only think of words that are one or the other. Inconsequential, trivial, useless are all *not important or no value* but none really encapsulate ***irrelevant***

Comment: @Hank Yeah, I'm not sure if I can capture both, but I'm going to try.

Comment: I understand where noisy came from - you have the signal that conveys the information, and the noise that interferes with conveying the information. Irrelevant is close, and may be better for a discussion based context, but doesn't cover cases such as misinformation, which is noise but not irrelevant.

Comment: Please clarify whether the thing not needed is strictly neutral, or if it might also be detrimental.  Math illustration: "*2+n*" -- if *n>0* it adds value, if *n=0* it adds no value, (but has a neutral result), and if *n<0* it both adds no value *and* reduces value.

Comment: "Noisy" is actually the most appropriate word for this use case, because of the analogue with voice conversations. A humorous remark might be acceptable when where are only a few comments, but it becomes "noise" when there are dozens of comments. People naturally reinterpret what noise is depending on the size of the crowd.

Comment: @200_success That's possibly very true, my reasoning for asking for a different word or phrase is because I'm not sure how many non-English speakers would be familiar with 'noise' being used that way. I'm just looking for other ways to say the thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's **[irrelevant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/irrelevant)**:

> Not connected with or relevant to something:
>   ‘an irrelevant comment’
>
> <sub>Oxford Dictionaries</sub>

What's nice about this word is it's simple. And it's also the word many people already use to describe this type of comment:

- [Should all irrelevant comments be flagged as noise?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78457/323179)
- [If I modify an old, unanswered question, why can't I modify the irrelevant comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106755/323179)
- One of Madara Uchiha♦'s [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334429/6083675):

  > Thus, it's the job of us moderators (as well as members of the community who voluntarily give up some of their time for the sake of the site), to remove noise. Noise being bad answers (which are voted down and/or edited), bad questions (which are voted down and/or closed and/or edited) and irrelevant comments (which are flagged and deleted).

Comment: Nice research on the many ways we already discuss comments.

Answer (score 24):

I like to use *[superfluous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superfluous)*:

> 1b:  not needed :  unnecessary
>   *<sub>from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superfluous)</sub>*

It can have a connotation of 'pointlessly excessive.'   If you have 3 elements when 1 is sufficient, and the other elements add no value, then the additional elements would be *superfluous.*

Comment: This fits as well as irrelevant. Maybe there is a way I can work with both.

Comment: This comment is superfluous, but not irrelevant.

Comment: In the specific of multiple elements where only one is needed, you would call the superfluous elements _redundant_.

Comment: Joke comments are superfluous, but are often well received, and not automatically worthy of deletion.

Answer (score 17):

How about *extraneous*?

M-W:

> [*extraneous*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extraneous):
>   not forming an essential or vital part; having no relevance

Your example:

> This should be deleted or removed because it is *extraneous*.

If it doesn't form an essential or vital part, it can be deleted or removed. Similarly, if it has no relevance, it can be deleted or removed. In both cases, it's noise.

Comment: I agree this is much better than "superfluous."  Many excellent comments are borderline irrelevant, but would never be described as "extraneous."  +1

Comment: This fits as well depending on the context.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to irrelevant, posted above in the comments, I would offer "inapplicable". Most forms have an n/a or "not applicable" option for survey choices, such as this multiple choice form: https://www.surveyconsole.com/images/help/help-120-1.gif
or this numerical example: http://images.slideplayer.com/26/8438090/slides/slide_9.jpg

Answer (score 4):

> - This should be deleted or removed because it **has been [floccinaucinihilipilificated](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccinaucinihilipilificate).**

### [floccinaucinihilipilificate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccinaucinihilipilification#Etymology)

> To describe, estimate or regard something as unimportant, having no value or being worthless (hybridized definition from the two wiktionary links above)

Comment: That word is so long that it has been floccinaucinihilipilificated.

Comment: Wow, haven't seen that word since I had too much time to read while I was laid up in the hospital with pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis.

Answer (score 0):

[Worthless](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/worthless), [valueless](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/valueless), [unsubstantial](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/unsubstantial) and [unsubstantiated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unsubstantiated) all come to mind.

Comment: I don't think unsubstantiated fits like the others. It means that it's not proven or backed up. That says nothing about the relevance or value of the item.

Comment: @Hank Valueless is um, a value statement.  Unsubstantiated provides a basis for that judgement by saying that value was not supported by the argument or comment provided.  A perhaps more circumspect way to say valueless. :-)  Shades of meaning.

Comment: I will agree that it can be tweaked to work but I don't think it provides the same effectiveness as the others that you posted. Too much of a stretch just to describe 50% of the OP's desire.

Comment: I concede your point.  But I might choose unsubstantiated anyway to prepare the battle space for an argument to follow. Also, the second meaning of unsubstantiated is "being without form or substance" which does directly apply.  That is, the <text under discussion> has no substance.

Answer (score 0):

I like non sequitur, especially if it is out of context. But to complete your sentence I would normally select irrelevant which I have +1'd.

Comment: The etymology of "context" is "weave together."

Answer (score 0):

Tautology:
In rhetoric, a tautology (from Greek ταὐτός, "the same" and λόγος, "word/idea") is a logical argument constructed in such a way, generally by repeating the same concept or assertion using different phrasing or terminology, that the proposition as stated is logically irrefutable, while obscuring the lack of evidence or valid reasoning supporting the stated conclusion.

Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(rhetoric)

Comment: Please add a reference for your answer, as ELU prefers objective answers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be deleted or removed because it is "[for naught](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/for+naught)". *For naught* means:

> without achievement or result
>
> Etymology: based on the literal meaning of naught (zero or nothing)

[Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms]

Comment: Your answer was flagged automatically as low quality for its length. Please follow the format next time you answer a question here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Either the comment helps (adds value) or it doesn't in which case it is not helpful or, it is ***unhelpful***.

ODO:

> **[unhelpful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/unhelpful)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **Not helpful.**
>
> ‘Don't you hate it when people give you ‘helpful feedback’ of an
>   unhelpful nature?’
>   ‘Removing the unhelpful heat from the debate,
>   which can all too easily become polarised, is a necessary first step.’

Answer (score 0):

**Unworthy**

Thought of this last night while trying to sleep, came back to share because it makes me grin when I think about you putting it on your official form.

Then this morning I came up with these -- which are in the same vein: for laughs -- ordered by descending likelihood that a user would need to look them up. (I like to imagine each word in the context you've provided, and you and yours staring at the option in the dropdown list, contemplating awarding it as the permanent mark which effectively stamps 'rejected' on someone else's work. lulz.)

**inutile**, **feckless**, **ineffectual**, **insufferable**, **expendable**, **dispensable**, **feeble**, **inoperable**, **counterproductive**, **unproductive**, **fruitless**, **distressing**, **useless**, **painful**,  **weak**, **stupid**

Answer (score 0):

**Impertinent**

Not pertinent to a particular matter; irrelevant:

From [Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impertinent)

Answer (score 0):

> This should be deleted or removed because it has been **obviated**.

**OBVIATE**
transitive verb
:  to anticipate and prevent (as a situation) or make unnecessary (as an action)

Example of **obviate** in a sentence:
The new medical treatment obviates the need for surgery.

Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obviate

Answer (score -1):

If it is something that should be removed both because it is not useful and there is already enough stuff, a nice word might be "superfluous"

Superfluous: (adj)

1
    *a* :  exceeding what is sufficient or necessary :  *extra*

```
*b* :  not needed :  unnecessary
```

2
obsolete :  marked by wastefulness :  *extravagant*

Comment: How is this different from Hellion’s answer from 2 hours before yours?

Answer (score -1):

I'm flagging this comment because it:

- **[actively detracts or adds nothing](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22actively%20detracts%22%20or%20%22adds%20nothing%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)**
- is rude, offensive, or spam
- is not constructive or is obsolete
- <s>is too chatty</s>
- other...